# redefine < operator to use in stl algorithms for strings

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, std

Is it possible to redefine `operator <` for strings without modifying std namespace, to make this operator use in standard algorithms? 
For example, I can write:

```
namespace std
{

    bool operator <(const std::string & rhs, const std::string & lhs)
    {
        std::cout << "lol";
        return false;
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> lol = { "a", "b", "ba", "aa" };
    std::sort(lol.begin(), lol.end());
}
```

and "lol" will be printed several times. But if I move `operator <` outside from std namespace, default `operator <` will be used and nothing will be printed. Is it possible to make `std::sort` using custom `operator <` without including it to std namespace?

Yes I know, I can pass another comparator to std::sort but it's interesting for me if I could do what I asked and how?

Also am I correct, that it's correct to add such template specialization to std namespace?

Update: This is not practical question, I just want to know how can I do that if it's possible.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort - please see all the overloads. And your `operator<` does not respect *strict weak ordering*.

Comment: First of all the rules of putting things in the `std` namespace are very strict. Unless you know the exceptions then just don't do it. And what's wrong with the normal [string comparison functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)? What is the purpose of creating your own comparison function? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Are the guts of your question merely that you want `std::sort` to order the strings differently?

Comment: So you kow what you are supposed to do and now want to know if you abuse the system correctly?

Comment: I think the downvotes are unreasonable. This question is well-written and has a compilable example. Please don't downvote just because the concepts here are dodgy.

Comment: For the record, your program exhibits undefined behavior, as the comparison function doesn't meet the requirements of strict weak ordering (in addition to the fact that it's illegal to put overloads into namespace `std` unless they depend on user-defined types).

Comment: @Bathsheba The question is not clear on the issue: what is the **goal** of the overload/specialization? Does the OP want an **overload or a specialization?**

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "_as the comparison function doesn't meet the requirements of strict weak ordering_" which requirement is not met?

Comment: @curiousguy Ah, wait, I misread. I take it back. It returns `false` for all inputs, which is legal and simply makes all strings equivalent to each other. Somehow my brain read it as `return true;`, which would violate all kinds of requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not.  Adding a function to the standard namespace is undefined behavior.  [namespace.std]/1 states:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

If you want to change how `std::sort` sorts then you can provide a lambda and define what you want

```
std::sort(std::begin(foo), std::end(foo), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { /* your code here */ });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer for the 2nd part of question. According to the 1st part, yes I know I can pass lamda or functional object, but it's interesting for me if it's possible to reefine < in such way.

Comment: @AndreyNekrasov You're not going to be able to define `operator <` in a way that it will be called.  You can use a functor/function/lambda and call the global version in there but that's not really saving you anything.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to redefine operator < for strings without modifiying std namespace

You can define the overload in another namespace, sure. But as you have found out, it will not be found by overload resolution unless explicitly qualified.

> Is it possible to make std::sort using custom operator < without including it to std namespace?

Yes, and you already seem to know how:

> Yes I know, I can pass another comparator to std::sort

This is exactly what the comparator argument is for.

> Also am I correct, that it's corect to add such template specialization to std namespace?

That is not a template specialization; It is a function definition and you may not add function definitions to std namespace - or else the behaviour is undefined. You would be allowed to add template specializations, but only if at least one type argument is a user defined type.

Comment: What you say is correct, but you may wish to amplify the last comment by noting that adding function definitions to `std` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter UB mentioned now.

Comment: +1 Just one more point: `std::sort` e.g. will always use the overload of `operator <` for `std::basic_string` that is inside `std` by precedence, even if another operator was visible inside the global namespace (bad idea) or even `std` (very bad idea).

Comment: @ArneVogel "_std::sort e.g. will always use the overload of operator < for std::basic_string that is inside std by precedence_" can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: A candidate in the current namespace always wins, and that's `std` for `std::sort`. This is simply how unqualified name lookup is defined in the standard. Also note that the namespace of the caller doesn't matter at all. This can appear highly incovenient, but if it did matter, this would mean that the same instantiation of the template might behave differently depending on the caller's namespace, which is very problematic from an ODR perspective. Here's a little example of how `foo::f()` wins simply by being in the same namespace as the immediate caller: https://ideone.com/hFHTij